# VS Code не видит А в названии папки админ

Tags: visual-studio-code

Путь C:/Users/Админ/AppData/Local/Programs/Python/Python39/python.exe
Он видит так: C:/Users/дмин/AppData/Local/Programs/Python/Python39/python.exe

Из за этого он выдаёт ошибку. Как это исправить ?

Comment: Пожалуйста, уточните вашу конкретную проблему или приведите более подробную информацию о том, что именно вам нужно. В текущем виде сложно понять, что именно вы спрашиваете.

Comment: В идеале не иметь юзера с русскими буквами.

Comment: И как сменить на английские ? Подскажи если не сложно, пожалуйста.